# Downgrading Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Eval to Essentials?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

So a month or so ago, I installed Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Eval.   The server was just being used as a quickbooks server (remote desktop only used for administration, only runs Quickbooks DB software & file sharing)

The finance team likes the new setup, so it's time to buy a license, but I realised now that Standard, isn't the "base level" package, it's "Essentials", and from what I can tell, there's no REAL need for standard.

Please tell me there's some way I can just buy Essentials, and it'll downgrade Windows 2012 Server Standard to Essentials, without me having to rebuild the entire machine, migrate quickbooks, etc.

Comment: Does your network already have Win servers and a domain?  If so, you don't want Essentials.

Comment: No domain, no other servers.  It's just a windows server for quickbooks.  Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to downgrade, you will need to start fresh with 2012 Essentials media.

Using the DISM command, you can go up, but not down.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825157.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[No, there is no "downgrade" path from Server 2012 Standard to Server 2012 Essentials](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64d98ed5-089b-4d8e-8ef0-8f66325b65af/windows-server-2012-standard-downgrade).

As noted in the comments, you might not want Essentials anyway, so check out the [Server 2012 editions comparison chart](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=38809) before you go any further anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I had to perform the same task.
I installed Server 2012 R2 Standard by mistake.
I already had the Windows essentials key label on the server. I just didn't see it.
To downgrade is simple:
Inside Windows, I run the installer of Server 2012 R2 Essential. During the install you will be asked:

```
maintain the files or not.
```

It´s possible and simple. You have the choice to maintain the files or not.
It finishes in about 15 minutes.